# Скачивание файлов определённого формата со страниц

Tags: linux, wget

Как скачать все файлы определенного формата с заданной страницы, а также страниц, на которые ведут ссылки с нее? Использовать предполагается `wget` или другую похожую программу, главное чтобы на linux работало.

Comment: `httrack` подойдёт?

Comment: `lftp` с этим справляется наилучшим образом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расширение к Firefox'у ScrapBook отлично справляется с этой задачей

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
wget -A mp3 --input-file=http://music
```

также можешь использовать httrack

Comment: так не работает

Comment: исправлено. ...